# How to call Activity method in an AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I would like to call an `Activity` method after the `onPostExecute` of my `AsyncTask`.
Do you know how I can do that?

I want to call in the `sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message)` method in the `onPostExecute`.

Answer (score 4):

One way is to pass an instance of the `Activity` through `PostTask` constructor, something like:

```
private class PostTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>
{
    private AsyncBigCalculActivity activity;

    public PostTask(AsyncBigCalculActivity activity)
    {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    // ...
}
```

and on creating the `PostTask` instance, pass the activity instance:

```
new PostTask(this).execute();
```

Now you can invoke `sendSMS()` from within `PostTask`, like:

```
activty.sendSMS(...);
```

---

Also note that if you are defining the `PostTask` as a private class inside the activty, then you can invoke `sendSMS()` like:

```
AsyncBigCalculActivity.this.sendSMS(...);
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a constructor and a global variable to your AsyncTask like this:

```
AsyncBigCalculActivity mActivity;

public PostTask(AsyncBigCalculActivity a) {
    mActivity = a;
}
```

Then simply use `mActivity.sendSMS("test", "test")` when you need it.

However, you should really have methods like `sendSMS()` in a utility class.

Answer (score 1):

If your `AsyncTask` is an inner class of your `Activity` then you should be able to call the `Activity` method from your `onPostExecute()`. Otherwise, you can send the `Context` to a constructor of your `AsyncTask` and uses that to call the method

Answer (score 0):

## Write a Callback

You can create a CallBack using an interface. This way you can use your `AsyncTask` with any activity. (Loosely coupled code)

**1) Create a Callback**

```
interface MyAsyncTaskCallBack{
 
   public void doStuff(String arg1,String arg2);

}
```

**2) Initialize the callback in your AsyncTask**

```
private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void>
{
     private MyAsyncTaskCallBackactivity callback;

     public MyTask(MyAsyncTaskCallBackactivity callback)
     {
          this.callback = callback;
     }

     //Call callback.doStuff(....phonenum, ....message); in your postExecute

}
```

**3) Implement the Callback in your Activity and override doStuff() method**

```
public YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements MyAsyncTaskCallBack{

      // Your Activity code 
      // new MyTask(this).execute("phonenum","msg");    //<--- This is how you run AsyncTask

      private void sendMessage(String num, String msg){

          // send msg logic
      }

     @Override
     public void doStuff(String arg1,String arg2){
         sendMessage(arg1,arg2);  // invoke activity method
     }

}
```

Comment: can you help with how to call Activity methods in the below call. As when i tried to call method it doesn't recognize it. I have callback in Activity  new MyTask(new MyAsyncTaskCallBack(){
                @Override
               public void doStuff(String result){
                    //Do something
                    this.activitymethod() // it doesn't recognize this method of activity though it is calling inside the activity. 
                }
            }, this.getApplication().getBaseContext()).execute(params);

Comment: In your activity create MyTask like this. --> new MyTask(this).execute(params) @Mr.Jay