# AsyncTask Android ProgressBar not showing [Possible Duplicate]

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-progressbar

first of all I want to say that i know there  a couple of similar question on S.O but non of them answered my question...

First of all let me show you my code:

I have a fragment that when it loads it sends a request to a server, parses the JSON the server returns and then returns the parsed JSON as an object.

I initialize a progress bar in the onCreateView method:

```
bar = (ProgressBar) mainView.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
```

and then I create an instance of the Asynctask extended class:

```
PolisotAsyncInfo task = new PolisotAsyncInfo();
```

and then call the execute method and after that call the get function:"

```
task.execute(new PolisotAsyncParameter(ClientMainActivity.mToken,ClientMainActivity.mUserID));
Object o = task.get();
```

> I think this is what i'm doing wrong but not sure, i need to use the
>   get() method because i need the data that the doInBackround
>   returns....

at this point the compiler goes to the onPreExecute method there i set the bar to visible:

```
bar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

after the the doInBackround methods run and does all kind of stuff that is not relevant

and then the onPostExecute method is called there I set the bar to GONE:

```
bar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

Any help would be appreciated guys, I'm kind of lost here...

thanks!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this line is your problem as you suspected,

```
Object o = task.get();
```

`get()` blocks the `UI Thread`. You have different options though to get the data depending on your exact needs and configuration.

1. You can call an `Activity` method from `onPostExecute()` to do something with the data. How you do that depends on if its an inner class or not. If it is then there is no problem. If it is a separate file then you can pass an `Activity` reference to your `AsyncTask`s constructor and use that to call the `Activity` method. [These SO answers show how to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419417/how-to-call-activity-method-in-an-asynctask)
2. You can also use an interface to create a callback when your `AsyncTask` has finished. [This SO answer covers doing this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12575068/how-to-get-the-result-of-onpostexecute-to-main-activity-because-asynctask-is-a)

Comment: thanks a lot @codeMagic you i was kind of losing my mind here:)